# How do you call wire pins that can be used as jumpers with your breadboard?

Tags: connector, terminology, terminal, jumper

I can't seem to find [these things](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0146DJR9Q) on electronics distributor websites. There is a bunch of various pins and connectors but I can't find these among them. What are they called? I tried "dupont 2.54mm connector/pin" and didn't get the results I expected.

Thank you.

Comment: I use #22 or #24 solid wire - no need to deal with those pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.1" pitch 0.025" square pins:

Once upon a time these things were called "Berg" connectors since then several other manufacturers are making compatible connectors

for a while there were just called "100 mil square pin header" connectors

Berg was aquired by FCI and the parts were called "Berconn Mini Latch SR"

FCI was aquired by Amphenol and the parts are now called "PV™, Basics+ Series".

Pin part number 75653-002LF

single pin Housing part number 65039-036LF

Somwhere along the line someone started calling these things "Dupont" I have no idea why they did that. but it's certaily easier to say than "PV™, Basics+" unfortunnately the real Dupont seems to not be acssociated with this in any way. and major distributors are not using the term Dupont.

Comment: I have no idea why they are called Dupont either. The only people I see calling them Dupont seem to be people who haven't used them very much. I first came to know them as Molex connectors but that isn't really helpful since Molex makes a lot of connectors. Connectors in general just have confusing naming schemes. For Molex they are specifically the SL series male crimp terminals, although female is much more common.

Comment: Yeah so far as I can tell the term "Dupont" comes from the "maker" scene

Comment: They are called "DuPont" because this product line was introduced by DuPont in the 1970s. They were originally sold branded as DuPont too.

Comment: In 1972 DuPont aquired Berg,  https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/business/1987/08/02/du-pont-turns-to-electronics/97b45df4-27de-44f1-aed8-f6e1c9b2aed9/ but SFAIK it was still trading as Berg (and later sold to FCI)

Answer (score 1):

I've always heard these referred to as "Male crimp pins". I won't post any links or recommend any places to buy them as that would be against the rules of this site, but it should give you a good search term.

Answer (score 1):

The generic term is "crimp contacts" if i'm not mistaken.